# Google Beacon Platform / Nearby Notifications

Tags: google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

In the Google Beacons / Dashboard you can create multiple Nearby Notifications attached to a single beacon. How does Google prioritise these natively when the beacon is detected? (Whilst we can add multiple notifications we can only get the first one in the list to trigger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris, your observation is correct. Nearby shows maximum 1 notification per beacon based on creation timestamp (e.g. when it was created in Google Beacons / Dashboard). Only the latest valid notification will be shown.